# Is there any way to adjust the space among precision, recall, f1 in the sklearn's classification report?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My class names are lengthy. So, when I save the classification report from sklearn in a txt file, the format looks messy. For example:

```
               precision    recall  f1-score   support

          カップ       0.96      0.94      0.95        69
          セット       0.70      0.61      0.65        23
          パウチ       0.96      0.92      0.94        53
       ビニール容器       0.53      0.47      0.50        19
           ビン       0.91      0.90      0.90       305
  プラ容器（ヤクルト型）       0.69      0.80      0.74        25
 プラ容器（ヨーグルト型）       0.94      0.53      0.68        32
       ペットボトル       0.98      0.98      0.98      1189
   ペットボトル（ミニ）       0.71      0.74      0.72        23
         ボトル缶       0.93      0.89      0.91        96
        ポーション       0.80      0.52      0.63        23
        箱（飲料）       0.76      0.77      0.76       134
   紙パック（Pキャン）       0.86      0.69      0.76        35
 紙パック（キャップ付き）       0.93      0.80      0.86       126
紙パック（ゲーブルトップ）       0.85      0.93      0.88        54
紙パック（ブリックパック）       0.84      0.90      0.87       277
    紙パック（円柱型）       0.90      0.56      0.69        16
            缶       0.89      0.96      0.92       429

     accuracy                           0.91      2928
    macro avg       0.84      0.77      0.80      2928
 weighted avg       0.91      0.91      0.91      2928
```

Is there any way to adjust the space among different metrics so that the alignment keeps same for all rows and columns?

I have looked into the [sklearn.metrics.classification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) parameters, but I have not found anything to adjust spacing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662398/scikit-learn-output-metrics-classification-report-into-csv-tab-delimited-format

Comment: Okay, that solves the problem indirectly but works for me. Thanks.